# Компьютер самопроизвольно перезагружается с обновлением?

Tags: windows, вирусы, пк, обновления

Суть вопроса в следующем. Было это поздно ночью, отошёл от компа (минут на 30) возвращаюсь, а он на перезагрузке и обновляется. Хотя я никаких таймером на обновление не ставил. Нормально ли это? Могла ли виндовс специально перезагрузиться для установки обновлений? Или это проделки вирусов?

Comment: Центр обновления Windows -> Дополнительные параметры -> Обновить - если эта опция включена, то компьютер будет автоматически перезагружаться для обновления, предварительно уведомив пользователя за 15 минут

Comment: нет, ничего такого не нашел... конкретно, опции обновить - нету. есть другие параметры, но там везде галочка снята

Comment: Если коротко - да, могла. Это винда, привыкай.